# Deixar submenu na largura do container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, submenu

Como deixar o submenu (dropdown) dentro da largura do container?
Onde tem a div com a classe: class="navbar-collapse collapse" coloquei (position: relative), deu certo porém o link do logo não funciona não é clicável.

Veja o link: http://wsnippets.com/demo/bootstrap-mega-menu/

Assim é o padrão do script: pasteboard.co/12NtG7PEO.png Mas gostaria que ficasse assim: pasteboard.co/12QapxzIV.png que o submenu não ficasse com a largura completa na tela.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta. Mas pelo que pude ver nesse seu exemplo, o que está deixando o submenu do tamanho do container é a classe `.megamenu`:

```
 div.navbar-collapse.collapse > ul > li.dropdown.menu-large.open > ul.megamenu 

.megamenu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Assim é o padrão do script: http://pasteboard.co/12NtG7PEO.png Mas gostaria que ficasse assim: http://pasteboard.co/12QapxzIV.png que o submenu não ficasse com a largura completa na tela.

Answer (score -1):

Adiciona um conteiner após o `<ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
    <div class="container"> 
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          ...
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          ...
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Assim é o padrão do script: http://pasteboard.co/12NtG7PEO.png Mas gostaria que ficasse assim: http://pasteboard.co/12QapxzIV.png que o submenu não ficasse com a largura completa na tela.